# Не работает require() в статичном файле Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Использую в качестве сервера `express.js`. Столкнулся с проблемой, что подключенный скрипт не распознаёт функцию `require()` со стандартной библиотекой fs.

Использовал уже и

```
app.use(express.static('public')) // Папка со стилями и скриптами
```

и

```
app.get("/public/js/script.js")
```

Ничего не помогает

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот этот код(ещё вопрос немного непонятный у вас)

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
```